# How to use selenium (or something else) on a WEBSITE made with flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, selenium-webdriver

There is a website, I want to use Selenium on, for some automation. It has two input elements (email and password) and a submit button. But Selenium is not able to find them. When I look at the page source, the body element (shown below) contains 3 script elements and nothing else.

```html
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
      application. For more information, see:
      https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js?version=1.0.588');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <!--  ========================== Firebase ====================================== -->
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-auth.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script> -->
  <script src="scripts/persistence.js"></script>

  <!-- <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional


    // var firebaseConfig = {
    //   apiKey: "AIzaSyAjUZaQsnyUL5m1Tnp3Q7T-sABWH9cRVk4",
    //   authDomain: "sellerapp-laam.firebaseapp.com",
    //   databaseURL: "https://sellerapp-laam.firebaseio.com",
    //   projectId: "sellerapp-laam",
    //   storageBucket: "sellerapp-laam.appspot.com",
    //   messagingSenderId: "950918923365",
    //   appId: "1:950918923365:web:284a33df076eb36989728c",
    //   measurementId: "G-4PNLNHYDY0"
    // };
    // // Initialize Firebase
    // firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    // firebase.analytics();
  </script> -->
  <script src="main.dart.js?version=1.0.588" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

When I inspect the DOM, there are several weird elements that start with "flt" such as `flt-glass-pane` or `flt-span`. The input fields seem to be inside the `flt-span` elements (or vice versa). I have experience with Selenium. But never worked with Flutter/Dart. Just want to programmatically put some texts in the two input fields (email and password) and click the submit button. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

If you check this link out

https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/renderers#command-line-options

You will find that flutter apps are deployed mostly by canvas renderer. This option generally uses a different technique of generating the website and doesnt produce the standard html, css and js code like React or Angular

Because of this automating using Selenium is not easy on flutter. I would strongly encorage to check out flutter driver which may be an alternative to selenium for

Comment: You mean the canvas element, used for games, animations, etc?

Comment: No its not the html canvas. Its a whole new way of rendering things in the browser